# React : Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

So, i have this code, in react :

```
const sidebar = document.getElementsByClassName("pro-sidebar");
```

and, further, i try to change the width value using

```
function openNav() {
sidebar.style.width = "250px";}
```

and `onClick={closeNav}` on a button , but when i try to push the button, it gives me the next error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined.

Why??

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: When you log `sidebar`, what do you get?

Answer (score 1):

We do not manually manipulate the DOM like this in React. Do something like this.

```
  return (
    <div style={styles.container} />
  )

...

let styles = {
  container: {
    width: '20px'
  }
}
```

You can use string interpolation on width to programmatically change it with your function.

Comment: and, wait, how can I do to change that witdh when i push a button?

Comment: @MaresGabriel Use state with the width and when user clicks the button change the state.  Reference the state in the styles object with string interpolation